# Converting image intensity values to a certain range of grayscale values

Tags: photoshop

I have a large set of photos scanned by an overhead scanner and they need to be microfilmed. However, for microfilming issues those photos ought to have a certain range of  absolute grayscale values. Can I achieve something like that with Photoshop as a batch process? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Microfilmed? In 2020?

Comment: "Batch process" makes me think of [ImageMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) or [GraphicsMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphicsMagick). I do _not_ know whether either of those tools can do exactly what you want or, what command line arguments you'd need to provide, but it might be worth a look.

Comment: @xenoid Yes, although microfilming is pretty old, it's an exceptional medium of storage that can have a life expectancy of 500 years and that cannot be altered or falsified easily. It's performed for vital and sensitive documents because it's somewhat complicated and costly but quite effective for storing data.

Comment: @Solomon Slow thank you very much, I'll check it out!